# Bind a razor model property to ng-model

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, razor, angular-ngmodel

I was wondering if this is possible?

```
<input type="hidden" name="pageCategory" ng-model="pageCategory" ng-init="pageCategory=@Model.Page.CategoryId">
```

Comment: The razor will be evaluated on the server then will go to the browser as the actual category Id.  The Angular code is all run in the browser, i.e. after the value is evaluated.  So, in short, yes it should work.

Comment: So what i need to do to have a model in angular with the razor model value

Comment: yes it is possible